# RedHat Linux Space Usage Problem

Tags: rhel, hard-disk, disk-usage

I recently downloaded something on my Redhat Linux computer, and it told me I was out of space. I checked my disk usage, and it says I've used 100% of my folder, but as you can see I still have almost 900Gb available. How can I reallocate some of that space to my user?

Here is a screenshot of my disk usage:
[image: 1]

I know this may be a basic question, but I can't find a way to give myself more space. Also, I have root access.

Please let me know if anything else is needed.

EDIT: output of df -h

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      901G  3.5G  852G   1% /
tmpfs                 1.9G  1.2M  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda3             194M   31M  154M  17% /boot
/dev/sda5             4.0G  3.7G  105M  98% /home
```

Comment: That does the output of `df -h` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a tiny `/home` partition (where your home directory is) and a huge system (`/`, root) partition.

You can create a directory for yourself outside `/home`, for example `/LARGE/sortinghat`, and create a symbolic link in your home directory:

```
ln -s /LARGE/sortinghat/LARGE ~/LARGE
```

Put all your large files under `~/LARGE`, and keep your most critical files in `/home`. This kind of setup is cumbersome, but can be useful if you have different backup policies for `/home` (small, critical data, often backed up) and `/LARGE` (huge, less critical data, backed up occasionally).

Alternatively, move `/home` to the root partition. This is best done from a live CD/USB as moving your home directory while you're logged in is delicate at best. You might take this opportunity to remove the `/home` partition and enlarge the root partition by that much:

1. Make `/dev/sda5` an LVM physical volume (`pvcreate`).
2. Add it to the `VolGroup00` volume group (`vgextend`).
3. Enlarge the `LogVol00` logical volume (`lvextend`).
4. Enlarge the filesystem on it (`resize2fs`)).

Alternatively, shrink `/` and enlarge `/home`. You can't shrink a mounted filesystem, so boot from a live CD/USB.

1. Shrink the filesystem (`resize2fs`).
2. Shrink the logical volume (`lvreduce`).
3. Create a new logical volume in the free space (`lvcreate`).
4. Create a filesystem on the new logical volume (`mke2fs`).
5. Move your data from the existing home partition to the new filesystem.
6. Turn `/dev/sda5` into an LVM physical volume and add it to the `VolGroup00` volume group (`pvcreate`, `vgextend`).
7. Add the new space to one of the existing logical volumes (`lvextend`) and extend the filesystem on it (`resize2fs`).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just out of curiosity, is this a default for home directory size? It seems sort of inconvenient (I didn't originally set up this computer, so if it was a set parameter then that would explain it).

Comment: @SortingHat I don't know whether it's a Red Hat default. It feels far too small for a default home partition size these days. I actually have a ~4GB `/home` at home, because I back it up straight to DVD, but I keep a lot of large files elsewhere. I consider this an advanced setup; if you want to split `/home` off, on a modern machine, I'd recommend allocating maybe 50GB for the root partition (less on a laptop, most people get by comfortably with 20GB) and everything else for `/home`.

Answer (score 0):

Disk Usage Analizer on your screenshot shows only data for your home directory. Home is treated as 100% and below that you can see size of directories in your home with percentage data.

For example `~/Desktop` directory is 55.1% of your home directory.

Using icons on the top of application window you can analyze another directories like `/mnt` or just `/`.